# Building an Adversary for a PRF game

Tags: pseudo-random-function, prime-numbers, number-theory, game

[image]

[image]

Here is the game:

[image]

How can I make an $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$-time adversary making only one query to its **Fn** oracle and achieving advantage $= 1 - 1/(p-1)$

Here is my idea so far:
query $2^{-1}$, which when it goes through the Encryption algorithm, will return 1. So,

```
Adversary A:
C <- Fn(2^{-1})
if C == 1 return 1
else return 0
```

When we query 2^{-1}:
\begin{align}
Y_1 &= (2^{-1})^e &\bmod p \\
Y_2 &= 2^e &\bmod p \\
Y &= (2^{-1}\cdot 2)^e &\bmod p \\
&= 1^e &\bmod p \\
&= 1 \text{ (for all e)}
\end{align}

Is this allowed? Is it okay to query $2^{-1}$. I am assuming here that $2^{-1}$ is in $Z_p$ as long as $2$ is relatively prime.

Is this Adversary correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s allowed by definition of the PRF’s domain. To complete the analysis, you must also analyze your adversary’s probability of outputting 1 in the RAND game.